# Using Storyboard Designer For Xamarin IOS App in VS 2015

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build and run a simple Xamarin IOS Single View project in VS 2015 using the iPhone simulator. The project creation is fine and I can run and see the empty project in my iPhone simulator but when I try and use the VS 2015 storyboard designer I get the error below. The remote connection to the Mac is fine , I m running VS 2015 Community Edition under Windows 10 using Parallels on my Mac. I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting to the Mac before using the designer but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue.

Thanks

Steve

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Contents of C:\Users\spric\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\14.0\iOSDesigner-3712.2016-10-29__10-08-39.log:
MDAddinsHash: 33f406fa2dcf214012c78cb846585f062b2e1d24

[2016-10-29 10:09:02.3] INFO: IDE notified that the list of assemblies referenced has changed
[2016-10-29 10:09:02.3] INFO: Not uploading assemblies because there is no remote session
[2016-10-29 10:09:37.2] INFO: IDE notified that the list of assemblies referenced has changed
[2016-10-29 10:09:37.2] INFO: Not uploading assemblies because there is no remote session
[2016-10-29 10:12:16.7] INFO: IDE notified that the list of assemblies referenced has changed
[2016-10-29 10:12:16.7] INFO: Not uploading assemblies because there is no remote session

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the iOS designer, same error as this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44358) which is a duplicate of this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44330).

The work around seems to be:

> ### Partial workaround
>
> 1. Open the storyboard once more in Xcode 8.
> 2. Under the storyboard properties, change "Opens In" to "Xcode 7.x".
>
> (See also the attached screenshot.)
>
> As indicated by the dialog that will appear, this is only a partial
>   workaround because it will remove Xcode 8 features:
>
> > Saving for Xcode 7.x will close your document and data for Xcode 8.0
> >     features will be removed.

if you dont have Xcode then you might be able to just replace the version at the top of your xib/storyboard with this, I havent tested this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11542" systemVersion="16B2555" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" colorMatched="NO">
    <dependencies>
        <development version="7000" identifier="xcode"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11524"/>
    </dependencies>
```